# In Multisite - main site blog post should be display in minisite or subsite

Tags: multisite

If we add a blog post in main site that post need to be display in minisite (subsite)

Comment: Do you want the post to be copied - like it should show up in the dashboard for the subsite? Or you just want it to be displayed in the subsite?

Comment: The blog post should be just display in subsite.If we add blog post that post need to be just display in subsite

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I can't write the whole solution for what you need, but to achieve this you need to add code to your theme using functions like these which help you to figure out which multisite you're on, and pull a post from a different multisite:

`get_current_blog_id()` - get current multisite site ID

`switch_to_blog(123)` - switch to multisite ID 123

`restore_current_blog()` - if you switched to a different site, switch back to the one you were on before

So if your 'main site' is blog ID '1' then you probably need to add some code to your theme that does something like this:

```
    $mainSite = 1;
    $currentSite = get_current_blog_id();

    if ($currentSite != $mainSite) {
    
        switch_to_blog($mainSite);
 
        // get_posts, WP_Query, etc. to get the posts you want

        // post loop to print the post

        restore_current_blog();
    }
```